# Remover [] de un array en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de eliminar `[]` de un `array` que contiene solo un objeto:

Es decir, tengo un array siempre con un solo objeto de la siguiente manera:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre: 'Jhon'
  }
]
```

Lo que trato es quitar los `[]` y convertirlo solo en objeto:

Resultado esperado:

```
{
  id: 1,
  nombre: 'Jhon'
}
```

Ahora lo estoy accediendo de la siguiente manera:

> `data[0].nommbre`

Intenté remover con `Object.assign({}, data)`

pero esta solo me agrega un `{}` quedando así:

```
{
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre: 'Jhon'
  }
}
```

Comment: si quieres el objeto dentro con acceder el elemento `0` ya lo tienes. `const persona = data[0]`

Comment: Lo que quiero es evitar el [0]

Comment: pero es que es una colección y los elementos de la coleccion se acceden por indice. Quizas si expones lo que quieres hacer y porque quieres evitar el 0. Se pueda hacer algo

Comment: Dudas existenciales

Comment: puedes un loop por ejemplo `for...of` pero si siempre vas a tener un elemento es más optimo acceder por el indice. `for (const elem of data) { console.log(elem); } `

Comment: `Object.assign({}, data[0])`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la sintaxis de [asignación desestructurante](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment). Esta sintaxis se añadió en ES6.

```
// esto accede el primer elemento y se guarda en la variable elem
// la variable se puede llamar como tu quieras
const [elem] = data;

// si tu array tuviera mas elementos puedes hacer lo mismo, cada variable se mapea al indice en el array
// indices 0 ,1 ,2
const [elem0, elem1, elem2] = data;

// si quieres saltar un elemento puedes usar la ,
// se saltan los elementos de los indices 0 y 1 respectivamente
const [, , elem2] = data;

// es una buena practica poner un comment para indicar que se está saltando dicho índice
const [/*elem0*/, /*elem1*/, elem2] = data;
```

Más info en la documentación.

Answer (score 0):

usa sintaxis de propagación para lograr el mismo resultado,
Ejemplo:

```
Object.assign({}, ['a','b','c']); // {0:"a", 1:"b", 2:"c"}
{ ...['a', 'b', 'c'] }
```